# Matrix multiplication vs equations for image transformations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to write some code to rotate an image in [MATLAB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATLAB), that is, equivalent to [imrotate](http://www.mathworks.se/help/images/ref/imrotate.html). I use matrix multiplication to perform an inverse mapping of the new image to the input image. However, it takes a lot longer than explicitly writing out the equivalent equation. Is there a better way to perform this multiplication?

I would prefer to use matrix multiplication, because I could use the same code for other transformations by replacing the transformation matrix, `RT`.

```
im1 = imread('file.jpg');
[h, w, p] = size(im1);
theta = -pi/6;
hh = round( h*cos(theta) + w*abs(sin(theta)));
ww = round( w*cos(theta) + h*abs(sin(theta)));

R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
T = [w/2; h/2];
RT = [inv(R) T; 0 0 1];
for z = 1:p
    for x = 1:ww
        for y = 1:hh
            % Using matrix multiplication
            i = zeros(3,1);
            i = RT*[x-ww/2; y-hh/2; 1];

            %Using explicit equations
            %i(1) = ( (x-ww/2)*cos(theta)+(y-hh/2)*sin(theta)+w/2);
            %i(2) = (-(x-ww/2)*sin(theta)+(y-hh/2)*cos(theta)+h/2);

            %% Nearest Neighbour
            i = round(i);
            if i(1)>0 && i(2)>0 && i(1)<=w && i(2)<=h
                im2(y,x,z) = im1(i(2),i(1),z);
            end
        end
    end
end

%Revised code
im1 = imread('file.jpg');
[h, w, p] = size(im1);
theta = (pi)/3;
hh = round(h*abs(cos(theta)) + w*abs(sin(theta)));
ww = round(w*abs(cos(theta)) + h*abs(sin(theta)));
im2 = zeros([hh,ww,p], class(im1));

R = [cos(theta) -sin(theta); sin(theta) cos(theta)];
T = [w/2; h/2];
RT = [inv(R) T; 0 0 1];

x=1:ww;
y=1:hh;

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
orig_pos = [X(:)' ; Y(:)' ; ones(1,numel(X))];
orig_pos_2 = [X(:)'-(ww/2) ; Y(:)'-(hh/2) ; ones(1,numel(X))];

new_pos = round(RT*orig_pos_2); % Round to nearest neighbour

% Check if new positions fall from map:
valid_pos = new_pos(1,:)>=1 & new_pos(1,:)<=w & new_pos(2,:)>=1 & new_pos(2,:)<=h;

orig_pos = orig_pos(:,valid_pos);
new_pos = new_pos(:,valid_pos);

siz = size(im1);
siz2 = size(im2);

% Expand the 2D indices to include the third dimension.
ind_orig_pos = sub2ind(siz2,orig_pos(2*ones(p,1),:),orig_pos(ones(p,1),:), (1:p)'*ones(1,length(orig_pos)));
ind_new_pos  = sub2ind(siz, new_pos(2*ones(p,1),:), new_pos(ones(p,1),:), (1:p)'*ones(1,length(new_pos)));

im2(ind_orig_pos) = im1(ind_new_pos);
imshow(im2);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should vectorize the for loops, it doesn't seem that hard. It'll gain you a lot. Trickiest is the position calculation and ignoring positions that fall off the image after rotation.

Solution:

```
x=1:ww
y=1:hh

[X, Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
orig_pos = [X(:)' ; Y(:)' ; ones(1,numel(X))];

new_pos = round(RT*orig_pos); % round to nearest neighbour

% check if new positions fall from map:
valid_pos = new_pos(1,:)>=1 & new_pos(1,:)<=w & new_pos(2,:)>=1 & new_pos(2,:)<=h;
```

You can do the assignment to the resulting matrix in a for loop to deal with positions to ignore, or just remove them from the source matrix and do the assignment in one blow:

```
orig_pos = orig_pos(:,valid_pos);
new_pos = new_pos(:,valid_pos);

siz = size(im1);
im2 = zeros(siz,class(im1));

% expand the 2d indices to include the third dimension
ind_orig_pos = sub2ind(siz,orig_pos(2*ones(siz(3),1),:),orig_pos(ones(siz(3),1),:), (1:siz(3))'*ones(1,N));
ind_new_pos  = sub2ind(siz, new_pos(2*ones(siz(3),1),:), new_pos(ones(siz(3),1),:), (1:siz(3))'*ones(1,N));

im2(ind_orig_pos) = im1(ind_new_pos);
```

Your code is probably also slow, because you don't initialize `im2` so it is expanded in runtime as needed.

As reference: using 'peppers.png' as source image, this whole block of code took 0.12s on my pc, your code took several minutes.. end result was the same.

Comment: Hey, thanks a million,exactly what I was looking for. I almost get it, a little confused on the last section. But I'll mess around with it a bit more

Comment: look in the documentation of sub2ind; It is needed because I have three coordinates (vector x, vector y, 1:3) that I want to use, but doing img(x,y,z) indexes a submatrix instead of the subelements. Look at the examples in the documentation and try some yourself to understand it ;) Also going through the code step-by-step and inspecting variables can explain a lot!

Comment: I've added my revised code above but it is having some strange effects that I cant explain, the image is rotating in the opposite direction to what I expect e.g. 30 degress produces a clockwise rotation rather than anti-clockwise. Some angles produce an empty array for new_pos e.g. 180 And a 90 degree turn has a black line on one side.

Comment: Solved the issue with the empty arrays, I was using negative dimensions for the size of the second Image. and the direction is the same as my previous code. The issue with the black lines is still unresolved

Comment: In conclusion the black lines are points that fall outside the map, they do not appear from the original code in which im2 is not initialised. I assume this is due to the way matlab handles the uninitialised array as the new_pos are equivalent in each case